# Wordpress - Change plugin option in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles, custom-wordpress-pages

For my website I’m using the plugin **Woocommerce Variations to Table Grid**, but I would like to restrict this one only for some roles ‘Administrator’ and ‘wholesaler’. (my website is for wholesalers and ‘normal’ customer)

Anyway I was thinking to just desactivate the plugin by checking the user role so I tried the following solution : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159085/deactivate-plugin-for-a-specific-user-group
Doesn’t work.

I’ve got a variable in my plugin called $vartable_disabled which is a boolean which “Disable globally” the plugin.

So I am thinking to do something in my functions.php like:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_option_change_plugins');    
function my_option_change_plugins()
{
    global $current_user;
    if (!in_array('administrator' || 'wholesaler', $current_user->roles)) {
        deactivate_plugins( // activate for variation-table
            $vartable_disabled == 0
                        $vartable_position == 'under'
        );
    } else { // desactivate for those than can't use it
        activate_plugins(
            $vartable_disabled == 1
                        $vartable_position == 'side'
        );
    }
```

But for sure I’m doing something wrong, I tried plenty of different thing the whole day, impossible to figure it out.

Anyone can help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally didn't work as expected because to change an option you need kind of "administrator" rights, so for the other roles like "customer" it didn't change the option as expected.

Anyway, instead I worked with the plugin developer (thanks Spyros) and the solution has been to hook directly in the plugin (functionnality now added to the new plugin version ;))

The following code has been added:

```
    //  if the table is disabled for this product display the default select menus
$checkcat = array();
if (is_array($vartable_categories_exc) && is_array($pcids)) {
  $checkcat = array_intersect($pcids, $vartable_categories_exc);
}

$checkrole = array();
if (is_array($vartable_roles_exc) && is_user_logged_in()) {
  $user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
  $checkrole = array_intersect($user_info->roles, $vartable_roles_exc);
}
if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_array($vartable_roles_exc) && in_array('guest', $vartable_roles_exc)) {
  $checkrole['guest'] = 'guest';
}

if ( 
  ((get_post_meta($product->id, 'disable_variations_table', true) == 1 || !empty($checkcat)) || $vartable_disabled == 1 || !empty($checkrole)) 
  && get_post_meta($product->id, 'disable_variations_table', true) != 2 
  && $vartable_shortcd != 1) {
  // Enqueue variation scripts
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

  // Load the template
  wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
      'available_variations'  => $product->get_available_variations(),
      'attributes'              => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
      'selected_attributes'     => $product->get_variation_default_attributes()
    ) );
  return;
}
```

Thanks everyone for your time/help.

Answer (score 0):

`deactivate_plugins` is need. base plugin name. But you are passing variables.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/deactivate_plugins

Comment: Hi Arshid.
Effectively I tried this one to deactivate depend on role basis. The thing is, impossible to reactivate the plugin on role basis after that (I guess that plugin activation are done at the launching). Anyway, I would like to kind of "mute" or pause the plugin on role basis.

Comment: I would like to disable plugin for a specific user role if I can't just dynamically change the option of my other plugin

Comment: Why you add two equal sign     '$vartable_disabled == 1'

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake but doesn't change anything, I can I access to this variable (of my plugin) dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution with the function "update_option()"

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_filter_the_plugins');
function my_filter_the_plugins()
{
    global $current_user;
    if (in_array('administrator', $current_user->roles)) {
        update_option( 'vartable_disabled', 0 );
    } else { // activate for those than can use it
        update_option( 'vartable_disabled', 1 );
    }
}
```

With that my plugin option switch to '1' (disabled).. but the thing is, it doesn't matter the role as it always go only for the first line..

I'm a bit lost, I don't understand why it works in one way but not the other.

My plugin fonction is:

```
   if ( ((get_post_meta($product->id, 'disable_variations_table', true) == 1 || !empty($checkcat)) || $vartable_disabled == 1) && $vartable_shortcd != 1) {
  // Enqueue variation scripts
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

  // Load the template
  wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
      'available_variations'  => $product->get_available_variations(),
      'attributes'              => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
      'selected_attributes'     => $product->get_variation_default_attributes()
    ) );
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a little misunderstanding of a point. A plugin can't be activated for an user and deactivated for another one (in the pure concept of Plugin Activation/Deactivation). It is globally **activated** or globally **deactivated**.

Said this, depending on the way that your plugin is programmed, its functions could be disabled to certain users or groups. Instead keeping trying the deactivation method you can, for example, find the parts where your plugin [admits to be filtered](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) and take advantage of that. If there is not filters, you can try:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( !in_array( array( 'administrator' , 'wholesaler' ) , (array) $current_user->roles ) ) {
    update_option( 'vartable_disabled' , 1 ); // Assuming 'vartable_disabled' parameter really disables the plugin for the current user
}
```

In addition, alike you can hide all the html related to that option (checkboxes, menu elements and others).

Comment: Yes it was a misunderstanding from the beginning.

Comment: However, I tried your solution and added this: else{
  update_option( 'vartable_disabled' , 0 );
 } but it has the same behaviour.. just turning off ('1') the plugin option (vartable_disable) but never turn it on ('0') when I change between admin/guest